# Language in mutt/neomutt

Tags: mutt

How do I set the language/translation in `mutt`/`neomutt`?

Can't seem to find any options for that here: https://www.neomutt.org/guide/configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your LANG variable appropriately.

If you want to change language only for mutt you can run command like:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 mutt
```